# Why doesn't my FPDF class function SetMargins() effect the first row?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am using the FPDF class to create a pdf based on the results from a mysql query. The information was outputted in a table to pdf as expected but my problem occurred when I used SetMargins() to set the page margins. Everything except the first row is effected. The first line seems to be hardcoded to a certain position or margin definition.

Here is my code:

```
class Table extends FPDF
{
    public function CreateTable($header, $data)
    {
        //Header
        $this->SetFillColor(255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B', 12);
        foreach ($header as $col) {
            $this->Cell($col[1], 10, $col[0], 1, 0, 'C');
            //Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])
        }

        $this->Ln();

        //Data
        $this->SetFillColor(255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
        foreach ($data as $row) {

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($row as $field) {
                $this->Cell($header[$i][1], 6, $field, 1, 0, 'C');
                $i++;

            }
            $this->Ln();
        }

    }
}


//column headings for the department table
$dept_header = array(array('Name', 75), array('Phone', 40), array('Fax', 40));

//column headings for the team tables
$team_header = array(array('Name', 35), array('Role', 30), array('Office', 25), array('Cell', 25), array('Email', 45), array('Pager', 25));

//get data
$query = new ConnectQuery();
$dept_data = $query->all('SELECT * FROM Table');

$team_data = $query->all('SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME), JOB_ROLE, OFFICE_PHONE, MOBILE_PHONE, EMAIL, PAGER_NUM FROM Table2');


$pdf = new Table('P', 'mm', 'Letter');

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins(5, 5);
$pdf->CreateTable($team_header, $team_data);
$pdf->CreateTable($dept_header, $dept_data);


$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just define the page margin BEFORE you add the first page. The position is not reset by setMargins() call, which results in the "hardcoded postition" which was set in AddPage():

```
$pdf = new Table('P', 'mm', 'Letter');
$pdf->SetMargins(5, 5);
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Comment: Fantastic! This makes a lot of sense and worked great.

Answer (score 1):

There's a property in the FPDF class called $cMargin, which is used to calculate the x-offset of the text before it gets printed within the cell, but there doesn't appear to be a setter for it. It's a public property, so after you've instantiated your FPDF class, just call:

```
$pdf = new fpdf('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->cMargin = 0;
```

Or you can workaround your 1st line like

```
$pdf->Ln(); //workaround for 1st line
  $pdf->Cell(..);
```

Comment: For reference to anybody curious reading this in the future, `$cMargin` is defined as `$margin/10` in the FPDF constructor.

Comment: The first solution was unsuccessful but the workaround works just fine. Of course, now I'm having SetFillColor()  problems with the first cell but that's a different question. Thanks for your help!